# Creating a socket to a website to retrieve that pages information

Tags: node.js, sockets, http, meteor, socket.io

How would I create a socket to a site to retrieve that pages information? If I'm using meteor do I have to do an HTTP.get in a loop(it's a multiplayer game so things are constantly changing) or is there a way to actually create a socket to the site. I looked at Socket.io but I was only able to find how to listen and accept, not actually create a socket to a site.

EDIT: In my case http://play.pokemonshowdown.com/ . I'm assuming if I keep doing http.get requests, it'll won't save the state and thus keep creating a new game. Could I somehow create a socket between my site/server to their site/server till I disconnect? Basically, whatever a browser does but I don't want to display that information but rather redirect it to another socket(not part of the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here depends upon what the site you want to connect to supports.  If it is just a web server that creates web pages, then your only option is to use an HTTP get operation to request a web page.

If the site supports a specific API, you can make an HTTP get operation to a specific API request and get a more structured response than just a web page.

If the site supports webSocket or socket.io connections with specific request/response messages defined, then you can connect with either a webSocket or socket.io.

But, it all depends upon what the receiving site supports.

---

If you are trying to do repeated requests from node.js, you would likely not use a loop, but more like a timer such as:

```
setInterval(function() {
    request.get(..., function(err, response, body) {
        // process error or response here
    });
}, 10* 1000);
```

It may also be the case that the `request` module is of use to you since it adds a lot of functionality on top of the `http` module when trying to retrieve requests from an HTTP server.

Comment: I see, what if it's a game site, but a mutliplayer game? In my case http://play.pokemonshowdown.com/ . I'm assuming if I keep doing http.get requests, it'll won't save the state and thus keep creating a new game. Could I somehow create a socket between my site/server to their site/server till I disconnect? Basically, whatever a browser does but I don't want to display that information but rather redirect it to another socket(not part of the question). I"ll edit my question.

Comment: @user99393939 - You will have to discover how the actual game site you're interested in hacking into actually works as there are several different possibilities.  I've described the three options in my answer.  You need to figure out which of those the specific site uses and supports.  A browser uses these same options I've outlined in my answer.   Typically, one would use code inspection and debugging tools to examine what the browser game is doing to figure out how it does what it does and therefore what the site's server supports.  This is called reverse engineering.